# Joining two tables conditionally on range of second (joined) table

Tags: php, mysql, join, range

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
store_products
----------------
ID | name | sold
----------------
ID => INT
name => STRING
sold => INT
```

Table 2

```
store_product_views
---------------------
productID | timestamp
---------------------
productID => INT
timestamp => INT
```

The relationship is set up as one-to-many where there are multiple `store_product_views` for one `store_product`.

The code is set up to log into `store_product_views` a `productID` and `timestamp` whenever an item from `store_products` is viewed.

I want to generate data that gets the product ID, the product name, the number of sold products and the total views of that product within a range of `timestamp`. This works correctly if I leave out the `AND views.timestamp >...` part.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT store_products.ID as id, name, sold, COUNT(views.productID) AS views 
FROM store_products 
JOIN store_products_views AS views ON store_products.ID = views.productID 
    AND views.timestamp > '".$options->start."' AND views.timestamp < '".$options->end."' 
GROUP BY store_products.ID
```

`$options->start` and `$options->end` contain a timestamp that I want to filter for the range. The problem is I only get data when timestamp is it its max value in the table. If I set the $options->end value to get a subset of the data, I get nothing at all.

Comment: Instead of a count function, make a subquery that uses count and the timestamps, this way you will still have the other data, get it? If you need a more clear example i can write some to you, but try yourself first :)

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to show products that were not viewed during the time range.

Comment: `AND views.timestamp BETWEEN '".$options->start."' AND '".$options->end."'` ? Also, do not embed variables in query, better use prepared statements.